# Accessing Data across two Databases

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have large set of data(more than 1TB). This will be accessed by more than 1000 people concurrently. Storing it in one database will make the application really slow. So I was planning to store it across different databases. Does mongo DB support routing between different databases? Or should this in our application? I am developing using Java and use Spring framework to interact with mongo.

Comment: WHat kind of research have you done?

Comment: I went through sharding. BUt it seems to be inside a one database

Comment: then shard both databases...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "routing between different databases"? MongoDB does not support cross collection or cross database operations. Generally you should be looking to build denormalized collections that provide all of the data needed in a single collection. Otherwise you will need to access multiple databases and collections individually from your application.

Comment: @JamesWahlin I want to basically distribute the users across 2 databases based on a criteria(location) so that the traffic will be distributed and the user will be routed to that particular database based on the criteria(location). Hope I am clear this time :)

Comment: 1TB doesn't seem like a lot of data for a single DB.  Nor do 1000 users - since they usually access data via an application layer.  Are you sure a single DB can't handle this load or are you guessing?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky SOrry I actually missed a 0 there. its 10,000. I am actually guessing. Can you tell me if 10,000 concurrent hits will make the data access slow.

Comment: there are people who are using MongoDB and applications handling far more accesses and more data than you are discussing here.  But whether your app will be slow depends on whether you design/write it to perform well and provision appropriate hardware resources, among other things.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Thanks for that. any for curiosity sake what is the limit that a single mongo DB can handle. i.e when should we think of have 2 servers/databases to avoid delay in fetching the data from the database

Comment: there is no "absolute" limits - you monitor performance of your mongo instance and when you see certain usage indicators trending up (or down) you plan to shard (which is splitting a single DB across more than one server - similar to using two servers but in a way that's more transparent to the application).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the reason for splitting your data into multiple databases is to improve performance, I would suggest [sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding/) a single database rather than splitting across multiple. If location is granular enough and you would like to split load across servers you could then use [tag aware sharding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tag+Aware+Sharding) to pin specific locations or location ranges to a specific server. There is a good tutorial on this available [here](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/07/25/controlling-collection-distribution/).

Before following this route I would suggest performing load tests on your application with your database on the hardware you plan to use for your system. It is worth confirming that you really do need to shard/split data and if so the # of servers you may need. If your database is going to be read rather than write intensive it could be that a non-sharded database would handle your load giving your [working set](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage#CheckingServerMemoryUsage-WorkingSetSize) fits in memory.